# Why do we return "head" and how is it being changed in this example?

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am new to linked lists, and have been trying to work on some example questions, to increase my understanding of them. Below, is my code from a singly linked list question, where we need to remove all the nodes in our list that are equal to our input value, then return the new head:

```
  public class ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode next;
      ListNode() {}
      ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
      ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
  }
 
class Solution {
    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        
        while( head != null && head.val == val)
        {
            head = head.next;
        }
        
        ListNode current = head;
        
        while(current != null && current.next != null)
        {
            if(current.next.val == val)
            {
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

### (Example)

```
Input: head = [1,2,6,3,4,5,6], val = 6

Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

I am wondering why we are returning "head" in this example, and how the head object is being changed, when we are only using "current." I apologize for my lack of understanding with this, and appreciate any explanation. Thank you for your time.

Comment: We need to return the `head` node of the list as we need a starting point to traverse the modified list. `current` is used as a pointer to the list at a particular iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Remember in a LinkedList we can only have sequential unlike an ArrayList

so a LinkedList say `a -> b -> c -> d`

if I give a node of in between say `c` there is no way you can access node `a` and 'b' as you stated it's a singly linked list

So it is important to return the head node (`a` in this case) so that the entire list can be traversed.

#### How is it being changed in your code?

In the while loop you are assigning `head = head.next`
If we compare with the above example head node is like pointing from node `a` to node `b` and so on.

To fix it simple store the head node in a temporary variable and return it without modifying it.

```java
public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        
        ListNode originalHead = head; // storing the original head node

        while( head != null && head.val == val)
        {
            head = head.next;
        }
        
        ListNode current = head;
        
        while(current != null && current.next != null)
        {
            if(current.next.val == val)
            {
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        return originalHead; // returning head node without modifying it
    }
```